# How to determine with template is running slow in ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have installed the CF 10 on my windows server 2008 R2. Now problem is that when I open site page it's take almost 30 second to load the page. My system is good and I think it's not an issue of my system performance. I think it's an issue of ColdFusion 10.

Comment: You are going to have to give us a lot more info before this question can be answered

Comment: What kind of information u want to answer?

Comment: What is your ColdFusion page doing? Anything which might take a while? If you turn on CF debug in the administrator, does the debug info show anything as taking a long time? If you create a page which just cfoutputs #now()#, does that take a long time? My personal guess would be a network lookup problem. use netstat to see whether any odd lookups are being performed and try disabling netbios if present in Window's network config.

Comment: Actually when I was using CF9 then everything is going well but after I install cf 10 is going laggy

Comment: Check to see if there is difference in you JVM settings

Comment: Did you install ColdFusion 10 on the same server as ColdFusion 9?  If so, did you fully uninstall ColdFusion 9, or just stop the ColdFusion 9 services?  And if the services were just stopped, did you remove the ColdFusion 9 IIS connectors from your web site(s)? If the ColdFusion 9 connectors are still in the mix, they can cause delays while the web server is trying to communicate with ColdFusion 9.

Comment: Voting to close at there's not a sensible amount of detail nor any demonstration the person has actually tried to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the server into debug mode, make sure dump out all the times it took to process all the templates. That will show you what is running slow. On the slowest templates, determine what this issue is.

Go to the CF Administrator -> Debugging And Logging -> Debugger Settings and choose "Enable Request Debugging Output"

You also may want to restrict the debug to your own IP, so that the whole world does not see debug.

See 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html

You should see something like this if you have it setup right

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me how to put server into debug mode?

Comment: log into the server at /CFIDE/administrator and go to the debug link on the left hand menu. also check the debug settings to make sure it's not restricting debug by IP address.